# implement addClass and removeClass functionality in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have couple of buttons for ListView and GridView. For switching between these 2 buttons I had written JQuery like below-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button.switcher").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var theid = $(this).attr("id");
            var theitems = $("ul#items");
            var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                // if currently clicked button has the active class
                // then we do nothing!
                return false;
            } else {
                // otherwise we are clicking on the inactive button
                // and in the process of switching views!
                if (theid == "gridview") {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $("#listview").removeClass("active");
                    // remove the list  view and change to grid
                    theitems.removeClass("tilelist");
                    theitems.addClass("gridlist");
                }

                else if (theid == "listview") {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $("#gridview").removeClass("active");
                    // remove the grid view and change to list
                    theitems.removeClass("gridlist")
                    theitems.addClass("tilelist");
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want move this functionality from Jquery to Angular2 typescript application. Can anyone please guide me on this? How do I implement addClass and removeClass functionality on button click from angular2 template?

Answer (score 81):

If you want to due this in component.ts

HTML:

```
<button class="class1 class2" (click)="clicked($event)">Click me</button>
```

Component:

```
clicked(event) {
  event.target.classList.add('class3'); // To ADD
  event.target.classList.remove('class1'); // To Remove
  event.target.classList.contains('class2'); // To check
  event.target.classList.toggle('class4'); // To toggle
}
```

For more options, examples and browser compatibility [visit this link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 14):

Try to use it via `[ngClass]` property:

```
<div class="button" [ngClass]="{active: isOn, disabled: isDisabled}"
         (click)="toggle(!isOn)">
         Click me!
     </div>`,
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not just using

```
<div [ngClass]="classes"> </div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: I was not aware about this. WIll try this option. Thanks :)

Comment: There is also `[class.someClass]="someBooleanExpressino"` for single classes. http://angular.io has lots of great docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically switch the class using [ngClass]

**for example**

```
<button [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item1'}" (click)="selectedItem = 'item1'">Button One</button>
<button [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item2'}" (click)="selectedItem = 'item2'">Button Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 13+ i got Malik's code to work using the following update:

Component:

```
clicked(event: any) {
    event.target.classList.add('class3'); // To add
    event.target.classList.remove('class1'); // To remove
    event.target.classList.contains('class2'); // To check
    event.target.classList.toggle('class4'); // To toggle
  }
```