# Angular 2/4 : How to add and remove class names from dynamically added elements from DOM

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to build a list (kind of a notification system you see on Face Book). the list is fetched using JSON, and generated on UI by ngFor. I have a default css class (unread which comes from JSON) applied to it. I wish to change that class on the DOM, dynamically based on any events (assuming a single button at the bottom for now). So basically I will have lot of DIV's generated, and out of that I have to change css class only on some of the nested span tags.

I can assign an unique ID's to span, so basically how do I target those spans using Angular 2 and change the css class.

Any pointers on how to go about it?. I am trying to achieve using Angular 2. Using plain javascript or jquery would be my last resort.

This my HTML:

```
 <ion-row *ngFor="let m of messages">
     <ion-col col-12 >
    <div class="talk-bubble border" [ngClass]="[m.position]">
      <span class="talktext">{{m.message}}</span>     
      <span #elem [attr.id]="m.iconId" class="message-status" [ngClass]="[m.status]" ></span>
      <span class="datedisplay">{{m.date}}</span>
    </div>
     </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716158/2235158

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implement addClass and removeClass functionality in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774014/implement-addclass-and-removeclass-functionality-in-angular2)

Comment: HI Malik, my question is little different, I am exploring how to add and remove classes from elements added dynamically to DOM

Comment: You could add an attribute in message object `unread: boolean = true/false` and in view `<div [class.unread]="msg.unread">` will solve your problem. Upon changing the status of msg object, class will also get changed.

Comment: OR: `<span  [ngClass]="{'unread': m.status == 'unread'}" ></span>`

Comment: Thank you @Malik, however I will have a button at the end where I intend to pass an ID of the span and change the css class. The reason is, I don't want to change all of the messages, just few messages. Any idea how can i achieve that?. Sorry to ask a lot. I am little new to Angular 2

Comment: You can achieve with pure javascript. Pass the id to `document.getelementbyid('span-id')`, and this will give you element, then link mentioned in above comments will tell you how to add/remove classes for element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind your object to the [ngClass] directive:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class-one': isClassOneActive, 'class-two': isClassTwoActive}">
```

Update the `isClassOneActive` and `isClassTwoActive` booleans in your typescript accordingly.

Comment: Hey Faisal, how do it if i have multiple elements and I have to target only specific elements.?

Comment: @Arun- please elaborate, some code will help if you can update your question with that!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ngClass` directive. Documentation can be found here:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass