# Angular 4 [ngClass] changes on click

Tags: angular

I try to chnage class a

item inside a *ngFor loop but only want to change the list-item selected.do you have any example for that case?

Thanks

Comment: give some more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implement addClass and removeClass functionality in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774014/implement-addclass-and-removeclass-functionality-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a reproduction of your problem, assuming you have the items template loop somewhat like this,

```
<item *ngFor="let element of list" [ngClass]="{ 'item-selected': element === selectedItem }"></item>
```

In your component,

```
list : any[]; // or the type of the list
// 'selectedItem' gets assigned the value of the current selected item everytime you select an item from the 'ngFor' loop's list of items.
```

If you show your code may be someone can pinpoint it rather than generalizing it. In the above template, the `ngClass` conditionally adds the class `.item-selected` when the current `element` in the `ngFor` loop is the `selectedItem`.

More on `ngClass` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#how-to-use). Hope it helps.