# How to remove button style or overwrite dynamically added classes to button in material2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have Open button

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openModal()
"type="button" color="primary">Open Modal </button>
```

On button button click, popup modal open and after close modal. `cdk-focused` and `cdk-program-focused` classes added and to this button and get some ripple effect on that.

I want to get rid of that style, want remove or overwrite those classes those added to button after close modal*

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774014/implement-addclass-and-removeclass-functionality-in-angular2

Comment: @VijaySankhat that if for only one button, wanted to implement for all the buttons in entire project.

Comment: then use [ngClass] for all the buttons

Comment: i want to remove dynamically added class, `[ngClass]`, could you tell me how to use `[ngClass]` to remove classes. i gone through this https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass.  but not getting

Comment: is there any way such like directive which can remove that classes from buttons in entire project

Comment: @Vega yes exactly

Comment: @Vegai just want to removed dynamically added those classes (`cdk-focused` and `cdk-program-focused`).

Comment: @Vega material 5.2

Comment: @Vega  go to https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples . see `Ocik one` button in console. Click on `pick one` btton after close popup you can see in console those classes added to button

Comment: @Vega i have added screenshot to my question, may that helps you to understand my prob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest two solutions:

**1.** First, set an additional class on that button in order to avoid that all the mat-raised-buttons be affected by the style change, it's not your aim, I suppose.

**HTML:**

`<button mat-raised-button class="myButton" (click)="openDialog();">Pick one</button>`

**CSS:**

```
.myButton:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
    transition:none !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}
```

Then you can set the style of mat-raised-button either by

a) setting it in component's stylesheet with ::ng-deep:

```
::ng-deep .myButton>.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-app-background{
  background: white !important
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iafpdh-xzfbn8)

b) setting with ViewEncapsulation.none:

**Class:**

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
...
    encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.myButton>.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

.myButton>.mat-app-background{
  background: white !important
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iafpdh-2m5xcs)

c) setting it in style.css:

```
.myButton>.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

.myButton>.mat-app-background{
  background: white !important
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iafpdh-7z1tfr)

2. The button gets the focus when you click on it. Turn away the focus from that button by setting the focus on an other element:

`...
<input matInput #input [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="What's your name?"> 
...
<button mat-raised-button class="myButton" (click)=" input.focus();openDialog() ">Pick one </button>`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iafpdh)

Comment: its working,  could you pls tell me which style should be used to remove that button effect

Comment: it's working fine when i put those styles in particular component's scss file.  But when i put those styles in my `styles.scss` file, it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

.mat-app-background{
  background: transparent !important
}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm for me, but can u explain how it worked

Answer (score 0):

Even I went through lots of trial and error method,but finally got fixed with it by adding following feature  while creating model.

in the diolog creation add this

restoreFocus:false

*Whether the dialog should restore focus to the
*previously-focused element, after it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with Angular 11 and inside mat-drawer for the first link it was adding this effect.
This span was being added inside first link whenever I open the mat-drawer

```
<span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
```

So I had to do this in my component's scss

```
::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

This may be similar to above answers, hope this will help someone working with mat-drawer.